# Does the "Copyfile" method of VBA works with either a Sharepoint online syncronized library or a Sharepoint online network drive?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint-online

Right now to access directly to files from a Sharepoint online document library without entering to any kind of browser,  there are two options:

1.- Sharepoint online syncronized library

2.-Sharepoint online network drive

(see more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/troubleshoot-mapped-network-drives)

So supposing you have either of those solutions already mapped into your computer as it were another C: drive, can VBA interact with any of those solutions with traditional methods as CopyFile and FSO ? Can anyone give me a heads up to some documentation about this ?

Thanks a lot in advance ¡

Comment: Did you try to do this ?

Comment: I haven´t actually because I need to demonstrate to my IT team it is possible to do that in order for them to create me the access, so i kind of wanted to be sure it can be done, but all the references that exist are for sharepoint 2013 and back, Im not sure is the "Synching" features of Share Point online are relatively new or something.

Answer (score 2):

Just mapped a SharePoint folder to Z:

```
Dim f
f = Dir("Z:\")
Do While f <> ""
    Debug.Print f
    f = Dir()
Loop

Dim fso As Object, fldr, fl
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set fldr = fso.getfolder("Z:\")
For Each fl In fldr.Files
    Debug.Print fl.Name
Next fl
```

both listing methods work fine.